# Image alignment is misplaced in interner explorer9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I am applying here liner gradient for ie9.pop up  is displaying but image alignment is misplaced compare to mozilla and chrome can any body tell to me what is the mistake.

this is my code:

```
.top_block {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    min-height: 150px;
    min-width: 105px;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#E9E9E9), to(#D3D3D3));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E9E9E9, #D3D3D3);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#E9E9E9', endColorstr='#D3D3D3',GradientType=0 );
    margin-left:72px;
    left: 36%;
    top: 32%;
    border: 6px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px;   
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: It would be great to make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) in order to test it.

Comment: Can you show a screen capture of your situation ?

Comment: well i'm not 100% clear on what you want but by looking at you css you have a margin-left and a left off-set, seems strange. show us what you are describing

Comment: Just a guess, but usually when you are specifying both a left and margin-left on a fixed position, you are trying to center an item on the screen, but the numbers are all off.  I would expect a left: 50%; margin-left: -52px in that case.  Are you a mac developer testing in chrome and firefox on your machine, and having someone else test in IE 9 on a different machine (with a different screen resolution) by any chance?